# state of migration scripts is "future"

Tags: flyway

Has anyone seen this?  What does it mean?

```
[flyway@bndba0 ~]$ flyway.sh -configFile=nilestg2.properties info
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.2.0.3
```

---

```
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version        | Description                | Installed on        | State   |
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 0              | << Flyway Init >>          | 2013-02-20 20:01:03 | Success |
| 2013.1.14.1    | setup                      | 2013-02-26 09:53:23 | Future  |
| 2013.1.15.2    | product site ets           | 2013-02-26 09:53:23 | Future  |
......
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Never mind.  Looks like "future" simply means flyway can't find the scripts which have been migrated.

Comment: This was a bug indeed, and has been fixed in SCM.

Comment: That's not correct - flyway can't find the scripts which have been migrated leads to "Missing".

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16982249/787375