# Flyway Info screen State is Future, not Missing

Tags: flyway

Due to a few company-specific features, which I need to swap in and out, I sometimes have migrated scripts which are not present in the sql directory when I run "info" or "migrate" at a later time.  I just noticed an inconsistency, though, in how this displays:

```
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version        | Description                | Installed on        | State   |
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
...
| 4.1            | Add new reports synonyms   | 2013-05-31 16:38:22 | Success |
| 4.1.1          | BRNC Add new reports synon | 2013-05-31 16:38:22 | Missing |
| 4.2            | Convert old DATA to DATA2  | 2013-05-31 16:38:22 | Success |
| 4.2.1          | BRNC Convert old DATA to D | 2013-05-31 16:38:22 | Future  |
+----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

So, "Success" means that scripts have been run, and "Missing" means they were run and are no longer present.  But what does "Future" mean?

This is similar but not identical to a question:

[state of migration scripts is "future"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145397/state-of-migration-scripts-is-future)

which was never officially answered, but where Axel Fontaine said in a comment that this had been fixed.  I checked, and my jars (3/18) are a later date than his comment (3/2).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it currently stands this is what these mean:

- **missing** -> executed, no longer found in configured locations, **older** than the newest found script
- **future** -> executed, no longer found in configured locations, **newer** than the newest found script

Coming to think of it though, I feel this minor distinction might not be worth a separate state in the info results. I will revisit this in time for 2.2.

Answer (score -1):

Future means installed sql files are future version files and do not exists in current(old) version dist.